# como obtengo el vagon de menor peso y como edito el nombre del vagon de un array?

Tags: java, array, metodos

En el siguiente codigo de la clase locomotora:`

```
public class Locomotora {

private int idLocomotora;
private String nombre;
private int cantidadMaximaDeVagones;
private Vagon formacion[];

public Locomotora(int idLocomotora, String nombre, int cantidadMaximaDeVagones) {
    this.idLocomotora = idLocomotora;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.formacion = new Vagon[cantidadMaximaDeVagones];

}

public Locomotora() {
    this.idLocomotora = 0;
    this.nombre = "";
    this.cantidadMaximaDeVagones = 0;
    formacion = new Vagon[cantidadMaximaDeVagones];
}

public boolean agregarVagon(Vagon vagon) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < formacion.length; i++) {
        if (formacion[i] == null) {
            formacion[i] = vagon;
            return true;

        }

    }

    return false;

}

public Vagon obtenerVagonDeMenorPeso() {

    Vagon vagonDeMenorPeso = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < formacion.length; i++) {
        if (formacion[i] != null) {
            if (vagonDeMenorPeso == null || vagonDeMenorPeso.getPesoDeCarga()< formacion[i].getPesoDeCarga()) {
                vagonDeMenorPeso = formacion[i];

            }

        }

    }

    return vagonDeMenorPeso;

}

public boolean editarNombreDeVagon(String idVagon, String nuevoNombreDeVagon) {

    boolean sePudoEditar = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < formacion.length && !sePudoEditar; i++) {
        if (formacion[i] != null);
        if (formacion[i].getIdVagon().equals(idVagon)) {
            formacion[i].setIdVagon(nuevoNombreDeVagon);
            sePudoEditar = true;

        }

    }

    return sePudoEditar;

}
```

El siguiente codigo es de la clase vagon,no pongo la clase main porque nose si sera necesario.

```
public class Vagon {

private String idVagon;
private String descripcion;
private MarcaVagon marca;
private double pesoMaximoSoportado;
private double pesoDeCarga;



public Vagon() {
    
}


public Vagon(String idVagon, String descripcion, MarcaVagon marca, double pesoMaximoSoportado, double pesoDeCarga) {
    this.idVagon = idVagon;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.pesoMaximoSoportado = pesoMaximoSoportado;
    this.pesoDeCarga = pesoDeCarga;
    
}
public  boolean validarIdentificadorDeVagon(String idVagon) {
    
    boolean valido= true;
    

    if(idVagon.length() != 6) {
        valido = false;
        
    }
    if(!idVagon.substring(0, 2).matches("[ A-Z]*")) {
        valido = false;
    }
    if(!idVagon.substring(3).matches("[ 0-9 ]*")) {
        valido = false;
        
    }
    return valido;
}

public String getIdVagon() {
    return idVagon;
}

public void setIdVagon(String idVagon) {
    this.idVagon = idVagon;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
}

public MarcaVagon getMarca() {
    return marca;
}

public void setMarca(MarcaVagon marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}

public double getPesoMaximoSoportado() {
    return pesoMaximoSoportado;
}

public void setPesoMaximoSoportado(double pesoMaximoSoportado) {
    this.pesoMaximoSoportado = pesoMaximoSoportado;
}

public double getPesoDeCarga() {
    return pesoDeCarga;
}

public void setPesoDeCarga(double pesoDeCarga) {
    this.pesoDeCarga = pesoDeCarga;
}
public String toString() {
    return "ID: " + idVagon + " - " + "Marca: " + marca + " - " + "Peso de carga: " + pesoDeCarga;
    
    
}
```

}

Bueno aclaro que es un modelo de examen que dieron para practicar en la universidad,recien estoy empezando a estudiar programacion y me cuesta un poco...los problemas que tengo es que al agregar el vagon no se agrega al array de formacion;y al obtener el vagon de menor peso me tira null o no me muestra nada por consola,y tampoco me sale el metodo editar vagon...espero puedan ayudarme!!!

Comment: Hola @matyas, hay varias cosas que se pueden mejorar, pero en general tu código está bastante bien, solo dos errores, **private MarcaVagon marca;**, o bien cambias todos los **MarcaVagon** por **String**, o creas un **enum** con las distintas marcas, yo cambié todo a **String** y me funcionó... hasta validar vagón probé, el otro error, muy sutil, está en **obtenerVagonDeMenorPeso()**, dentro del **if** tienes la condición **vagonDeMenorPeso == null || vagonDeMenorPeso.getPesoDeCarga() < formacion[ i ].getPesoDeCarga()**, en vez de ""menor que"", debes usar ""mayor que"".

Comment: Hola @MarcePuente muchas gracias por marcarme los errores,te agradeceria mucho si podes compartirme el codigo,ya que sigo intentando y sigue sin salirme,no se si lo que estoy haciendo mal esta en la clase main,si podrias motrarme la clase main te super agradeceria!!!

Answer (score 0):

Cambios en la clase Vagon:

```
private String marca; // MarcaVagon por String

public Vagon( String id_Vago, String descripcion, String marca, double pesoMaximoSoportado, double pesoDeCarga ) {
   if( validarIdentificadorDeVagon( id_Vago ) ) {  // MarcaVagon por String
      this.idVagon = id_Vago;
      this.descripcion = descripcion;
      this.marca = marca;
      this.pesoMaximoSoportado = pesoMaximoSoportado;
      this.pesoDeCarga = pesoDeCarga;
   }
 }

 public String getMarca() {  // MarcaVagon por String
    return marca;
 }

Acá me tomé el atrevimiento de modificar el constructor, para  
verificar el "id" del vagon, le agregué el "if".  
Luego cambié cada aparición de "MarcaVagon" por "String".
```

en Locomotora:

```
public Vagon obtenerVagonDeMenorPeso() {
   Vagon vagonDeMenorPeso = null;
   for( int i = 0; i < formacion.length; i++ ) {
     if( formacion[ i ] != null ) {
        if( vagonDeMenorPeso == null || vagonDeMenorPeso.getPesoDeCarga() > formacion[ i ].getPesoDeCarga() ) {
           vagonDeMenorPeso = formacion[ i ];
        }
      }
    }
    return vagonDeMenorPeso;
}

Solo cambié "<" por ">".
```

en el main:

```
 public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Locomotora loco = new Locomotora( 0, "la chancha", 4 );
    Vagon vago = new Vagon( "AC7887", "vagon", "mac", 88, 71 );
    System.out.println(  loco.agregarVagon( vago ) );
   
    Vagon vago1 = new Vagon( "BB7886", "vagona", "mac", 97, 72 );
    System.out.println(  loco.agregarVagon( vago1 ) );
   
    Vagon vago2 = new Vagon( "CC7885", "vagonaz", "mac", 12, 73 );
    System.out.println(  loco.agregarVagon( vago2 ) );
   
    Vagon vago3 = new Vagon( "DD7884", "vagonazo", "mac", 123, 70 );
    System.out.println(  loco.agregarVagon( vago3 ) );
   
    System.out.println( "" );
    System.out.println( loco.obtenerVagonDeMenorPeso() );
    System.out.println( (loco.getVagones())[0] );
}
```

Espero que te funcione, sino avisame.

Comment: muchas gracias @MarcePuente por la ayuda,super agradecido!!

Comment: @matyas, Un placer ayudarte!